# Unnesting customDimensions w/ BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've got a Standard SQL query written to pull some Google Analytics data out of BigQuery. I've pasted a simplified version below that I use for testing:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id))
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING), '.', CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) AS session_id
  FROM `myproject.ga_sessions_20180227`, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
);
```

Running this query outputs a unique session count of 6,696, which is accurate when compared to the GA UI.

However, when I introduce customDimensions into the query, I lose a number of rows. Running this query only outputs 6,606 unique sessions.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id))
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING), '.', CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) AS session_id,
    MAX(IF(customs.index = 14, customs.value, NULL)) AS custom_id
  FROM `myproject.ga_sessions_20180227`, UNNEST(customDimensions) AS customs
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
);
```

I'm not using *hits.customDimensions*, because the custom dimension in question is based on the user level, not the hit level. If I don't group the output, I get an error.

How can I unnest a non-hit based custom dimension without losing rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `CROSS JOIN` (the comma): when cross joining a table with `NULL` - or in this case an empty customDimensions - the result is `NULL` in total instead of only the left table. 
You want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN` because this preserves the left table:

```
FROM `table` LEFT JOIN customDimensions AS cd
```

Besides that you can also use a simple sub-select instead of joining sub-tables/arrays:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT value FROM t.customDimensions WHERE index=1) AS cd1
  , COUNT(1) AS Qty
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20180202` AS t
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. But how do I also UNNEST(hits) within the same query?

Comment: If you need only an aggregated or specific value from hits, you can also write a sub-select for that similar to the customDimensions one.